# Set object property to be the same as File Owner property in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, iboutlet

I have a `NSWindow` in a nib-file owned by a `MYWindowController`. The nib-file has a bunch of `MYViewController` objects. I wan't to set `MYViewController.managedObjectContext` to be the same as `MYWindowController.managedObjectContext` but I'm not able to connect those two in Interface Builder.

Is doing this in code my only option? E.g. in `MyWindowController`:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad { // or awakeFromNib
    self.myViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that type of connection in Interface Builder.